# CSS attribute from bootstrap.css not being recognized by Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to ruby and this is my first stackoverflow question (although I've used previous questions and answers a ton - thank you stackoverflow community for that!) so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I've seen other questions posted about problems with Heroku and boostrap.css, but this isn't so much an outright error as it is something not working quite as expected.

I recently added a top nav bar in my Rails 3 app using the stylings provided by boostrap.css. In the documentation, they recommend adding padding-top: 40px to the css file to make room for the nav bar.

The padding looks right on localhost but for whatever reason is not working in Heroku. The rest of the boostrap css appears to be correct (button colors, table attributes etc) but I cannot make the padding stick. An easy workaround would be adding some 
 tags at the top of my index.html file, but I'd like to understand why this is happening in case it's indicative of a larger css problem.

Code added to bootstrap.css file for padding:

```
html, body {padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;   
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 40px; 
}
```

index.html code:

```
<div class="topbar">
<div class="fill">
    <div class="container">
        <h3><%= link_to 'Your Book Club', homes_path %></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to 'Home', homes_path %></li>
            <li class="active"><%= link_to 'Books', books_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Locations', locations_path %></li>
            <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </form>
      <ul class="nav secondary-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#" class="menu">Account stuff will go here</a>
            <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Dolor sit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Amet Consequeter</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Enough with the Latin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<h1>Which books do you want to read as part of our book club?</h1>

<br />

<h3>Instructions:</h3>

<br />

<p>1. Vote for any of the books below that you'd like to read</p>

<br /><br/>

<p>2. And/or:

    <button type="submit" class="btn"><%= link_to 'Add a New Book', new_book_path %></button></p>

    <br /><br/>

<p>3.

    <button type="submit" class="btn info"><a href="./locations">Vote on     Locations</a></button> 


            <br /><br />

<table class="zebra-striped">
<tr>
<th>Title (Click name to see description)</th>
<th>ISBN</th>
<th>How many votes does it have?</th>
<th>Vote for this book</th>
<th></th>
</tr>


<% @books.each do |book| %>
<tr>

<td><%= link_to book.title, book %></td>
<td><%= book.isbn %></td>
<td><%= pluralize(book.votes.length, "vote") %></td>
<td><%= link_to '+1', votes_path(:book_id => book.id), :method => :post %></td>  
<td><span class="label important"><%= link_to 'Delete', book, confirm: 'Are you sure?',             
                method: :delete %></span></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

</div>

</table>

<br />
```

Comment: Did you remember to commit and push with the padding set appropriately? Have you tried a hard refresh (just to make sure you're not seeing stale css)?

Comment: I've committed several times (moved css to bottom of file, then top) but nothing. I opened up the app in a different browser and it looks the same (no padding). You can check it out here: http://simple-water-5927.herokuapp.com/books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't catch that you're using Asset Pipeline. That's what your problem is; you need to precompile your assets before you commit and push: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git ci -a -m "Compile assets for production"
git push
```

Note that if you're on Celadon Cedar there are some hooks that will do this for you on slug compilation, which is really convenient.

Comment: Wow thanks that certainly did something! Problem is, now all of the other styling from bootstrap.css are gone (from Heroku, not localhost). Do you know why the css on Heroku looks different from the css on my local server?

Comment: I just moved my CSS from the books.css.scss (for my books model) file to application.css.scss and now the padding works in Heroku! Must have something to do with the asset pipeline, which I am now learning about here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Thank you to coreyward for your help!

Comment: No problem! Did you add a line to import bootstrap.css into your application.css file?

Comment: No, I just copy-pasted the css. How would I do that with adding a line?

Comment: At the top of `application.css` use `//= require bootstrap` and then the next line `//= require_self`. Then the bootstrap.css code will be added before everything in application.css and they will be minified and combined together in production.